# What is the State of Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog

What  is the state of activity when it is displaying a notification or alert message. either **onStop**() or **onPaue**()

Answer (score 3):

onPause() will call when the Activity is visible to the user but no more has focus to interacting with user like a notification and alert message pops up to the user , and onStop() will call when the Activity is no longer visible to the user.

you can have more information on Activity Lifecycle on : [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)